# Issue with java Calendar result?

Tags: java

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -2);
    Date result = c.getTime();
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(result));
```

The above snap shot was working code of my project module.But today i noticed that i am getting wrong out put as ,

```
Tue Dec 29 15:49:32 IST 2015
2016-12-29
```

my expected result is

```
Tue Dec 29 15:49:32 IST 2015
2015-12-29
```

I noticed the code is working up to feb 26 2016 (tested by changing system date.)

what is the issue here ,Thanks in sdvance

Comment: i am using the same code :( , try to move to java 8 the date has been changed

Comment: me also working with java8

Comment: (new LocalDate()).plusDays(5);

Comment: what are u using now is not java 8 ability

Comment: why this issue is getting ?

Comment: this is the full answer :LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse("2016-02-29"); 
LocalDate addedDate = parsedDate.plusDays(1);